# how to attach vf email template in trigger

Tags: visualforce, trigger, email-template

I need to attach visualforce email template in a trigger while firing mail,how to achieve this?

```
trigger contentdoclinkattchment on Invention_Disclosure_New__c (after update) {
 if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isUpdate)
         for(Invention_Disclosure_New__c idf : Trigger.new){
         if(idf.Disclosure_Status__c == 'Closed - Application Approved for Filing')
         {

            Id newDocLink = Trigger.new[0].Id;
            //Id linkedEntityId = [select Id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =: newDocLink].LinkedEntityId;


            List<SymphonyIPM__Invention_Disclosure_New__c> ListInvendisclosure =[select Id,SymphonyIPM__Title__c  from SymphonyIPM__Invention_Disclosure_New__c where id =: newDocLink];
            if(ListInvendisclosure.size() > 0){
                set<ID> lstDocId = new set<ID>();
                List<ContentDocumentLink> lstContentDocumentLinks =[SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id
                                                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:newDocLink];               

                for(ContentDocumentLink docit : lstContentDocumentLinks)                                    
                    lstDocId.add(docit.ContentDocumentId);                                            

                List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{};
                    List<ContentVersion> documents=
                    [
                        SELECT Id, Title,PathOnClient,VersionData,isLatest,ContentDocumentId
                        FROM ContentVersion
                        WHERE isLatest = true AND ContentDocumentId IN :lstDocId
                    ];
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                

                for (ContentVersion document: documents) {
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    attachment.setBody(document.VersionData); 
                    //attachment.contenttype(document.ContentDocument.FileExtension);
                    attachment.setFileName(document.PathOnClient);
                    System.debug(document.Title);
                    attachments.add(attachment);
                }


                semail.setSubject('Attachment Details');//Read from custom settings
                String[] filters = new String[]{'In-house Counsel','Platform Inventor'};
                List<user> lstUserEmail =[SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Profile.Name lIKE :filters];
                String[] sendTo = new String[]{}; 
                for(user tmpUser:lstUserEmail)
                sendTo.add(tmpUser.Email);

                system.debug(sendTo);
                semail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

                String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi,New Invention Disclosure entitled '+ListInvendisclosure[0].SymphonyIPM__Title__c+',has been submitted for review.Please refer the attached document for the complete information of the submitted disclosure.</body></html>';
                system.debug(messageBody);
                semail.setHtmlBody(messageBody); 
                semail.setFileAttachments(attachments);
                if(attachments.size() > 0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});}
                system.debug('sendingemail');                

            }
         }  
     } 
   }

}
```

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: i need to add an vf email template here while sending mail

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is found under the Messaging Namespace of the Apex Developer Guide in the [Email Class (Base Email Methods)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm).

> **setTemplateID(templateId)**
>
> The ID of the template to be merged to create this email. You must specify a value for setTemplateId, setHtmlBody, or setPlainTextBody. Or, you can define both setHtmlBody and setPlainTextBody.

Add the above line with the Id of the template to the following section of your code as shown:

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                

    semail.setTemplateId(someTemplateId); // <-- specify template Id here

    //...

    semail.setSubject('Attachment Details');//Read from custom settings
    String[] filters = new String[]{'In-house Counsel','Platform Inventor'};
    List<user> lstUserEmail =[SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Profile.Name lIKE :filters];
    String[] sendTo = new String[]{}; 
    for(user tmpUser:lstUserEmail)sendTo.add(tmpUser.Email);
    system.debug(sendTo);
    semail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

    String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi,New Invention Disclosure entitled '+ListInvendisclosure[0].SymphonyIPM__Title__c+',has been submitted for review.Please refer the attached document for the complete information of the submitted disclosure.</body></html>';
    system.debug(messageBody);
    semail.setHtmlBody(messageBody); 
    semail.setFileAttachments(attachments);
    if(attachments.size() > 0){
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});}
    system.debug('sendingemail');
```